# Angular loadChildren property absolute path to module is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to lazy load a module from my app-routing.module.ts and the only way it works is if I use a relative path such as:

```
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] },
```

If I do the following it fails and says: ERROR in Could not resolve module app/admin/admin.module relative to /C/projects/my-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:

```
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] }
```

Did something change in later versions of Angular where this path must be relative and not absolute? Why is it working in their demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/moybyqrjdeom

In the Angular documentation it says the following:

The address is the AdminModule file location (relative to the app root), followed by a # separator, followed by the name of the exported module class, AdminModule.

Comment: I had the same problem and only got it to work with relative path.

Comment: Yep this has changed in Angular 6, in Angular 5 the app/... worked for me, but it stopped working in Angular 6. It has something to do with updated tsconfig.

Comment: Looks like `ng update` adds `"baseUrl": "./"` to the *tsconfig.json*, if you went that route to get to ng 6. And, the latest CLI includes that in the base *tsconfig.json* by default. So, that would do it.

Answer (score 3):

The build is based on your tsconfig. If you are using a CLI generated angular application then you should have two configs.

Inside your routing try doing this:

```
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'src/app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] }
```

if you `app/tsconfig` just extends `tsconfig` on the root this should solve that issue.

Your outer tsconfig should have `baseUrl: "."`

Answer (score 0):

Because importing with

```
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] }
```

Angular will search for module from root which is not available there.
Angular simply does not detect your modules so you need to provide correct path.